# Basis of subgroup of free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $F_2$ be a free group on $2$ generators $a, b$. We know $b$ and a conjugate of $b$, which is different from $b$, generate rank 2 free subgroup of $F_2$ and they are free generating set of the subgroup. In fact, if we take $b$ and automorphic image of $b$, they generate either rank 2 or rank 1 free subgroup but in both cases $b$ can be part of basis. Now if we take a word $w \in F_2$ and take $\alpha(w),$ where $\alpha \in Aut(F_2)$, then again $w$ is a part of a basis of the subgroup $\langle w, \alpha(w) \rangle$.

Now we take two words $w_1, w_2 \in F_2$ such that they generate rank 2 subgroup. For $\alpha \in Aut(F_2)$, when can we say that $w_1, w_2$ both can be a part of basis of the subgroup $\langle w_1, w_2, \alpha(w_1), \alpha(w_2) \rangle$?

If the subgroup $\langle w_1, w_2, \alpha(w_1), \alpha(w_2) \rangle$ has rank 4, then here $w_1, w_2$ are part of basis.

If the subgroup $\langle w_1, w_2, \alpha(w_1), \alpha(w_2) \rangle$ has rank 2 or 3, in this case, I doubt that $w_1, w_2$ will be a part of basis. Although, I do not know any counterexamples.

Thanks!

Comment: How about $w_1=a^2$, $w_2=ab^2$, $\alpha$ swaps $a$ and $b$, then $\langle w_1,w_2,\alpha(w_1),\alpha(w_2) \rangle = F$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks!